# Minimum packages required for Ubuntu Server to run Octave 3.8.x with GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, xterm, octave

I have a **Ubuntu 14.0 server** with no graphical interface. I created this server only to use **Octave** on it. Now that there is a GUI for the recent version of **Octave 3.8.x** available I wanna know what is the least requirement for **Ubuntu** that I can install and run the GUI for Octave.

I say minimum since I want this server to be as light weight as possible.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

### [If using Windows or any operation system that Putty can run on it]

I found the way myself. Apparently you actually don't need ANY graphical interface for Ubuntu server. All needed is a **Putty**. All you need is to Putty to the server however before you do you need to enable "**Enable X11 forwarding**" option under

Putty Configuration page > Connection > SSH > X11

[image]

and also have Xming installed and running in the background.

This means you're all sorted and you can run any software which requires an X server to build a GUI for itself. Just type

```
$ octave --force-gui
```

to fire it up.